# What to do with questions followed by completely wrong instant self-answers?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, wrong-answers, behavior, instant-self-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571169/android-studio-is-not-recognise-my-one-plus-two-in-linux) has raised a few red flags for me:

- The question itself is a duplicate (the topic has been discussed many
  times)
- The self-answer was instant
- The answer started with the infamous "I did many things - not sure which one worked"
- The answer was completely wrong

If it would have been just one or two of those things - I would have down- or close- voted it and moved on. But all of them at once? Yet both the question and the answer got some upvotes. I am really confused.

Comment: Just let the meta-effect kick in ...

Comment: If it's a duplicate, flag it as such. Leave a comment on the question explaining the fact that it is a duplicate. Leave a comment on the answer explaining why there is a better way - and link to the answer in the referenced question. Seems straightforward.

Comment: Answer with no idea what worked -> downvote (not particularly useful IMO).  Dupe question -> close vote and down vote for laziness.  Instant self answer to poor question -> looks like rep whoring -> call upon meta to punish the infedel.

Comment: I agree that the question being a duplicate was the most straight-forward part of my meta question. I guess it's the self-answer being that far off what prompted me to seek meta's help.

Comment: VTC the question as a duplicate, and DV the incorrect answer just like you would any other incorrect answer. Self-answered questions have the same requirements as any other question and answer: the question has to be appropriate and of good quality, and the answer has to be correct and well-written.

Answer (score 11):

Self-answered questions, particularly ones that appear to be posted instantly (when really they're just using a [built-in feature hardly anyone seems to know about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)), will always be a point of contention:

- You'll have users voting on the question and answer on their own merits. As it was meant to be. Some of the really well-researched and well-written ones go on to become popular, and the ones that are really, really bad get cleaned up just as quickly as any other low-quality question.
- Then you'll have users downvoting, commenting, *and* flagging them for moderator attention, because God forbid people solve their own problems and want to share their knowledge with others so future searchers can find the solution right away.
- And then you'll have users upvoting for the sole reason that the user took the time to utilize such a feature, regardless of how well they've actually used it or whether they've gone through the usual steps prior to asking a question beforehand (and shown evidence of such, if applicable).

So, yeah. I can't explain the upvotes on this one. I wouldn't say the question is abysmal, but it's not very good either. I don't know enough about Android to comment on the technical veracity of the answer, but its original revision (prior to deletion and my posting this) contains a disclaimer that makes me really uncomfortable. It's worse when you have to end your answer with the following note:

> I know it does not fit SO guideline exactly, but I am allowed to answer my own questions(as SO allows this), this is strictly for sharing knowledge, i have posted it here so that others if felt stuck can use help.

The feature was given to you to make your life easier, not so you can use it as an excuse to post a question that *you know* does not conform to the guidelines.

As always, if the question is a duplicate, vote to close it as such. If the answer is wrong, let the user know however you deem fit (on the answer itself, of course). Do the usual things you would do with any other question and any other answer by any other user.